# How to log fully detailed XMPP message sent and received by Prosody IM

Tags: xmpp, jitsi, prosody-im

I try to analyze a problem related to XMPP. I have two server components joined the same MUC room on Prosody IM (it's hard to make my application to print those XMPPs they received/sent , i'm using jitsi jicofo and jitsi jigasi).

So, I was wondering if it is possible to print detailed XMPP messages sent/received in MUC.

My prosody logging configuration is as below:

```lua
log = {
        { levels = {min = "debug"} , to = "console"};
}
```

Above configuration gave me log output as follows:

```
c2s55b17ab56330                                         debug   Received[c2s]: <presence type='unavailable' id='AwXwU-149' to='123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4'>
conference.example.com:muc                              debug   session qvagnu083x5-bl78@example.com/tYARglho is leaving occupant 123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4
c2s55b17b2a8300                                         debug   Sending[c2s]: <presence from='123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4' id='AwXwU-149' type='unavailable' to='tiqmjoyi7d3rr69-@example.com/9W3u-kLN'>
c2s55b17ae40d40                                         debug   Sending[c2s]: <presence from='123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4' id='AwXwU-149' to='focus@auth.example.com/focus32210095996901258' type='unavailable' xmlns='jabber:client'>
c2s55b17ab56330                                         debug   Sending[c2s]: <presence from='123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4' id='AwXwU-149' type='unavailable' to='qvagnu083x5-bl78@example.com/tYARglho'>
c2s55b17ae40d40                                         debug   Received[c2s]: <iq type='set' id='1hORO-3097' to='123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4'>
c2s55b17ae40d40                                         debug   Sending[c2s]: <iq from='123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4' type='error' id='1hORO-3097' to='focus@auth.example.com/focus32210095996901258'>
```

Let's take *line #3* above for example.

Prosody IM printed `Sending[c2s]: <presence from='123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4' id='AwXwU-149' type='unavailable' to='tiqmjoyi7d3rr69-@example.com/9W3u-kLN'>` .

However, the full XMPP message is:

```xml
<presence from='123456789@conference.example.com/448ddea4' id='AwXwU-149' to='tiqmjoyi7d3rr69-@example.com/9W3u-kLN' type='unavailable'
    xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <x
        xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
        <item role='none' jid='qvagnu083x5-bl78@example.com/tYARglho' affiliation='none'/>
    </x>
</presence>
```

My problem is how can I optimize the logging configuration for Prosody IM to get fully detailed XMPP message as above.

And I have checked their documents:

1. [Advanced logging configuration](https://prosody.im/doc/advanced_logging)
2. [Logging](https://prosody.im/doc/logging)

Found nothing on this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally figured out how to log fully detailed XMPP message in Prosody IM.

You will need `mod_stanza_debug` to achieve this.

From [Prosody IM website](https://prosody.im/doc/modules/mod_stanza_debug):

```
This module logs full stanzas to the debug log for the purposes of debugging.
```

It has been bundled in Prosody Installation. Just enable it by editing `modules_enabled` entry in Prosody global configuration file:

```lua
modules_enabled = {
        
        -- debug stanza
        "stanza_debug";

};
```

And finally , I can get the fully detailed XMPP message:

```
2021-09-01 12:10:51 c2s5577181821d0  debug    Sending[c2s]: <presence xmlns='jabber:client' from='123456789@conference.example.com/01f9f60c' to='jw5c6zuqagigmxyc@example.com/P2Z4rvii' id='Y81Xr-178'>
2021-09-01 12:10:51 c2s5577181821d0  debug    SEND: <presence xmlns='jabber:client' from='123456789@conference.example.com/01f9f60c' to='jw5c6zuqagigmxyc@example.com/P2Z4rvii' id='Y81Xr-178'><info os='l' v='13204'/><role role='participant'/><transcription-status status='OFF'/><nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>Transcriber</nick><stat name='version' value='Jigasi 1.1.SNAPSHOT'/><features xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'><feature var='http://jitsi.org/protocol/jigasi'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:jingle:dtmf:0'/></features><c hash='sha-1' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' node='http://jitsi.org' ver='qo0cQuyj88ya15Au4O5PVYxqmqA='/><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'><item affiliation='none' role='participant' jid='tfccagysjks6zjon@example.com/7XCp5aWX'/></x></presence>
2021-09-01 12:10:51 c2s557717e02950  debug    Sending[c2s]: <presence xmlns='jabber:client' from='123456789@conference.example.com/01f9f60c' to='focus@auth.example.com/focus32236264938572098' id='Y81Xr-178'>
2021-09-01 12:10:51 c2s557717e02950  debug    SEND: <presence xmlns='jabber:client' from='123456789@conference.example.com/01f9f60c' to='focus@auth.example.com/focus32236264938572098' id='Y81Xr-178'><info os='l' v='13204'/><role role='participant'/><transcription-status status='OFF'/><nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>Transcriber</nick><stat name='version' value='Jigasi 1.1.SNAPSHOT'/><features xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'><feature var='http://jitsi.org/protocol/jigasi'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:jingle:dtmf:0'/></features><c hash='sha-1' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' node='http://jitsi.org' ver='qo0cQuyj88ya15Au4O5PVYxqmqA='/><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'><item affiliation='none' role='participant' jid='tfccagysjks6zjon@example.com/7XCp5aWX'/></x></presence>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. can you tell how I can add stanza listener in Jicofo side for incoming xmpp messages from prosody

Comment: @MMSmmsbd maybe you can do something like this : https://gist.github.com/ankanch/2fe307b97058ebcd8e582d1db28c9df3 . I only tested it on jigasi, not jicofo.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out, I've added similar stanza listener in Jicofo xmpp , although there found presence stanzas, not all the IQ, or messages stanzas .